# How to use use 2 or more HC-SR04 sensors as one single sensor?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I'm new to Arduino and this is my problem. I need to track an object in a room. For now I have placed 3 sensors on the edges of each axis (x, y, z), where the x axis will the line between the east and the west walls of the room, the y axis will be the north and south walls of the room, and the z axis will be the ceiling of the room.

I have written code to get the output as x, y, z coordinates. But since the HC-SR04 has no horizontal range it can only track objects in its line of sight. Due to this I'm not able to fulfil my requirements. So I thought if I could couple up an array of HC-SR04s together to work as one sensor I can get more horizontal range.

Is this possible using an Arduino Uno R3? If it's possible, please guide me through it.

Comment: You can try to use them sequentially. Or try triggering all sensors for one axis at once an wait for an echo signal at any of the echo pins (each one at it's own Arduino pin). For the first approach you may run into performance issues depending on the number of sensors. For the second you may see interference effects with the multiple sound waves interacting. Try and test. If this is successfull, please come back and answer your own question, so that everyone can profit from it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try attaching your HC-SR04 sensor to a servo, then you will have a range of detecting an object in 180 degree span.

[image: Sample]

Of course you will have to make modifications to fit your purpose. Using three ultrasonic sensors with each of them having their own servo of 180 degree range will surely increase accuracy. To get started visit [here](https://howtomechatronics.com/projects/arduino-radar-project/). 
Hope this was what you were looking for.

(Image credits: Dejan Nedelkovski)